# Detect when navigation drawer changes open/closed state

Tags: android

How can I detect when a navigation drawer changes its open/close state? I need to be notified when the navigation drawer is going from a closed to open state. The content of the navigation drawer may need to be updated and I need to make these updates before the drawer opens. If the drawer was already opened previously, it won't cause a recomposition. The navigation drawer is a Material3 component running under Jetpack Compose.

This code does detect when the drawer is opening, but it's kind of too later. The drawer has already started to open by the time event gets fired and users can see the drawer's content. I need to update the content before the drawer is even shown open:

```kotlin
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState (Closed) {
        // fires every time the drawer changes state.
        true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LaunchedEffect(drawerState.isOpen) {
    if (drawerState.isOpen) {
       // you can update content here
    } else {
        
    }
}
```